# Custom line-endings in git (other than LF and CR+LF)

Tags: git, delimiter, line-endings

I was hired as a consultant to work with a terrible in-house [DSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) used by a large corporation.

I say terrible because instead of carriage returns or linefeeds to end each line of code, lines of code are separated with the five-character ASCII string `<EOL>`. These files are thousands of "lines" long. Any embedded carriage returns or linefeeds tend to crash their interpreter.

I cannot change their interpreter or language, but I need to work with a massive (>100 MB) codebase written in this language.

Before making any changes to this code, I want to put it into a git repository to track it. Is there a way to tell git that the string `<EOL>` represents an end-of-line, much like you can specify `LF` or `CR+LF` with `core.eol=lf`? For example, `core.eol="<EOL>"`. If so, this would make my life rather easier in two ways:

1. It would make merges and diffs work intelligently; git would know where the "lines" are.
2. I could (for example) check in the original code with `<EOL>` as the line ending, then check it out on another machine with `core.eol=lf` set, and git would convert back and forth automatically. (I could use a regular text editor and regular tools!)

I do recognize that this is a niche, edge case. I also understand I could add an intermediate processing step to convert back and forth before interacting with git, but I want to avoid that unless absolutely necessary, as I'd prefer to import their existing codebase directly into git without pre-processing it first.

If this feature is not available, I might even prefer creating a custom version of git to adding an extra processing step, so if anyone knows what complexities might be involved in that, I'd be interested in learning about those.

Comment: I don't think this is possible in git normally. You could set up some scripts to convert back and forth between normal line endings and whatever string you want to use, and just run the scripts before committing and after pulling. Clumsy but possibly the closest you'll get without forking git.

Comment: By the way, that DSL format sure is odd. There must be some story behind it. It must have been useful and necessary at *some* point for *some* reason. Does anyone there know what that reason was?

Comment: @torek As best I've been able to gather, the original developer wanted to make a language that resembled HTML so he used `<EOL>` much like HTML uses `<BR>`. I think the idea was to create a language that ignores whitespace, like C which uses semicolons to delimit program lines rather than carriage returns. But he used "tags" for everything that C might use a character for. So we also have `<AND>` and `<PLUS>` and so on. (Why their interpreter crashes when an actual end of line character is encountered, I have no idea...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This custom filter setup will result in `*.dsl` files containing `<EOL>` in Git storage, but `\n` when checked out in your working directory. Tools such as `git diff` will operate on the checked-out versions (e.g. `\n`). Is that what you want?

`~/.gitconfig` or `.git/config`

```
[filter "crazy-eol"]
    clean = awk 'BEGIN{ORS="<EOL>"}1'
    smudge = awk 'BEGIN{RS="<EOL>"}1'
[diff "crazy-eol"]
    textconv = awk 'BEGIN{RS="<EOL>"}1'
```

`.gitattributes` or `.git/info/attributes`

```
*.dsl filter=crazy-eol diff=crazy-eol
```

Comment: Interesting that the `1` is required to keep awk from just exiting. I would have used `{print}` myself. I wonder if `1` is faster? :-)

Comment: @torek `awk 'pattern'` is shorthand for `awk 'pattern { print }'`, and `1` is always true. I'd expect it to have exactly the same speed.

Comment: I think this would work. Then I'd simply omit those extra configuration lines in cases where I *need* the `<EOL>`s (such as when importing the original codebase, or when exporting code to run). The only question is whether it's better to do it this way or the reverse (storing `\n`s in Git), but regardless, this solves things!

Comment: @JohnSpeeks I realized that the original config results in diffs being done on the "clean" versions (e.g. with `<EOL>`), which may be... pretty unreadable. That's easy to fix though.

Comment: @ephemient The potential unreadability of the diffs was why I was thinking it might be better to store `\n`s in Git, and then change to `<EOL>` upon extraction when necessary. I am not sure, but I have a feeling I might run into other tools that have similar problems; might reduce complexity overall to just use `\n`s.

Comment: @JohnSpeeks Personally, I'd keep data in Git as pristine as possible, and modify the local "view" of it as convenient. Outside of Git, few tools will care; they're working only with the exported files, not the underlying repo. But choose whatever works best for you. This sounds pretty annoying to work with :-/

Answer (score 2):

There *is* a way to do this.  It's not convenient at all, and it runs the risk of making un-invert-able changes if the literal string `<EOL>` really *does* appear inside a line (although given your description of the DSL it seems like this cannot happen).

You cannot do it with the `core.eol` settings, though.  You will need to use *smudge* and *clean* filters.  Look at the description in [the gitattributes documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitattributes.html).  Your two filters will convert `<EOL>` to line-feed and vice versa.  This is, in fact, exactly what the `core.eol` and `core.autocrlf` and `text` conversion filters do: they replace `\r\n` with `\n` in one direction or another, just as you would replace `<EOL>` with `\n` in one direction or another.  In fact, if you look a bit further down in the documentation, in the "Interaction between checkin/checkout attributes" section, you will see that Git simply has a `text` filter that acts like a clean and/or smudge filter, as part of a pipeline.

#### Before you do any of this, consider ...

Before you bother with this, consider just doing a one-time pass of your own.  Once you have the file in "normal" form, you can Git-ize those.  You can always run your own sanitizer before working on these files.  Then, once you have the files ready to go, you run them through a "insanitizer" to go back to the crazy `<EOL>` format, all outside Git entirely.

I think this (external sanitizer/insanitizer) will be easier to work with, really.

Comment: I appreciate your explanation of smudge and clean here; it clears up exactly what's going on there. I had no idea that filters existed in Git. (I accepted @ephemient's answer as it included actual working configuration files, but it was a very close call.)

Comment: Yeah, I didn't suggest awk because (a) I wasn't sure you had it and more importantly (b) I didn't actually think of using awk at first anyway—I was thinking of writing a dinky little filter in C or something. :-)